# Do not parse string when using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have this (in one string):

```
5: <null>,
6: <null>,
7: 5
```

I want to remove the lines that contain `<null>`. My current expression is this:

```
@"[\d-]" + ": <null>,"
```

I am pretty sure the reason it is not working is because regex is parsing the 2nd part and I do not want it to. Any help?

Comment: well you are looking for "5  :" but your input has "5: "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I am one of those people that doesn't use Regex for everything... so here is a non-Regex version:

```
var result = input.Split('\n').Where(x => !x.Contains("<null>")).ToArray();
```

Then perhaps use `Join` to create a single string afterwards:

```
var originalWithoutNulls = string.Join("\n", result);
```

Comment: Hehe. Maybe, pm100. Anyways, this works beautifully! Thank you a ton!

Comment: +1. @pm100 - some history on the quote http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 : Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe simple `Where` + `Contains`/`IndexOf` instead of RegEx:

```
string[] lines =...
var filteredLines = lines.Where(line => line.IndexOf("<null>") == -1).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is patterned by numbers (if not I can redo) use that as a pattern to match off of. Here I used named captures to get the key values pairs and put them into a dictionary.

```
var data = @"5: <null>,
6: <null>,
7: 5";

var dictResult = 
Regex.Matches(data, @"^(?<Key>\d+):\s(?<Value>\d+)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .ToDictionary (mt => mt.Groups["Key"].Value, mt => mt.Groups["Value"].Value);

     Console.WriteLine (dictResult["7"]); // Prints 5
     Console.WriteLine (dictResult.ContainsKey("5")); // False
```